# Fade in hidden element

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps

I can fade in / out using the following code

```
<Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
     <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PauseImage" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
     <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PauseImage" />
</Storyboard>
```

To fadein:

```
EnterStoryboard.Begin();
```

To fadeout:

```
ExitStoryboard.Begin();
```

How can I fadein if the element is hidden **from the beginning** (I tried to set `opacity=0` and `visibility=collapsed`).

**EDIT:**
based on AstiK solution, here's the new `Storyboard`s (Instead of the built-in `FadeInThemeAnimation` / `FadeOutThemeAnimation`)

```
<Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:00.3"  Storyboard.TargetName="Image"/>
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="1" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.3"  Storyboard.TargetName="Image"/>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Do you want to animate when the element is hidden?

Comment: Yes, I want to fadein from hidden

Comment: I haven't checked it,But what about setting the control visible before starting the FadeIn animation?

Comment: dont u see? I tried to set the visibility to collapsed before the animation but IT DOES NOT work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original approach, you should have kept `Opacity ="0"` and `Visibility="Visible"` from the beginning. I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<Grid Height="50" Width="100" Background="Red" Opacity="0">
        <Grid.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard  >
                                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:03"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Style>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Didnt solve my problem but used some of your code to solve the problem. will edit my post in 1 min

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<Storyboard  x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="PauseImage">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PauseImage" />
```

set to collapsed in the same way for `ExitStoryboard`

Comment: It doesnt animate. just setting the visibility to different value (Visible or Collapsed), am I missing something?

Comment: did you mix up fade in and fade out? For your enter animation it should fade in, no?

Comment: please read: did you mix up fade in and fade out? For your enter animation you have a fade out animation